# Java generics compiler error assigning to JavaFX collection

Tags: java, generics, collections, interface

Consider the following code:

```
public interface ListDisplayObj {
    public String getListDisplayString();
}

public class BusinessObject implements ListDisplayObj {
    ...
     public String getListDisplayString() {
          return "Example String";
     }
}

public class DBUtilityClass {
    public ObservableList<BusinessObject> getMyBusinessObjects() {
        ObservableList<BusinessObject> toReturn =
            FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        // add some values to list
        return toReturn;
    }
}

public class JavaFXGuiController  implements Initializable {

    @FXML private ListView<ListDisplayObj> listItems;

    @Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb)
{
        ObservableList<ListDisplayObj> objsForList =
            DBUtilityClass.getMyBusinessObjects();
        listItems.setItems(objsForList);
        ...
    }
}
```

The assignment in initialize() is generating an "incompatible types" compile error between the return type of the `getMyBusinessObjects()` function and the `objsForList` type.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

setItems requires a list of the exact type (ObservableList instead of ObservableList), whereas your list is of an implementation of the interface. Define listItems as a ListView.

Comment: Thanks, I tried removing the type from the ObservableList (I think that's what you were suggesting) - while that fixed the compile error it generated new ones preventing the use of a cellFactory specific to the interface type. The whole point of using the interface was to abstract different business object types within a single ListView - to provide a common means of displaying different objects in the list.

Comment: No you can't go from a list of BusinessObject to a list of ListDisplayObj via casting. Because the code that deals with a List of BusinessObjects expect all items in the list to be a BusinessObject. If you cast, then some other code could put another implementation of ListDisplayObj. So you probably just need to change the return type of getMyBusinessObjects to ObservableList<ListDisplayObj>. Or have a specific function that converts from one list type to another...